# Camera problems with the STM3243I board

Tags: camera, embedded, stm32

I am working with the STM32439I-EVAL2 board and I have problems when I use the camera. I have been testing the MB1063 Demonstration example from the STM32CubeF4 software development and when I try to use the camera shows this message: "Error while Initializing Camera Interface. Please, chech if the camera module is mounted". The camera module is mounted and connected to the board, but it does not work and I need to use it. Which could be the problem? It´s necessary a previous configuration? The board is new, camera could be damaged?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reflash the board with the demo example? Or are you using it as it came?

I had the same problem with the STM3240G-EVAL, but the problem was fixed when I re-flashed it with the demo code. Hit reset after flashing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.1.0\Drivers\BSP\STM324x9I_EVAL\stm324x9i_eval_io.c

```
uint8_t BSP_IO_Init(void)
{
uint8_t ret = IO_ERROR;

 /* Read ID and verify the IO expander is ready */
 if(stmpe1600_io_drv.ReadID(IO_I2C_ADDRESS) == STMPE1600_ID)
{
 /* Initialize the IO driver structure */
 io_driver = &stmpe1600_io_drv;
 ret = IO_OK;
}

if(ret == IO_OK)
{
 io_driver->Init(IO_I2C_ADDRESS);
 io_driver->Start(IO_I2C_ADDRESS, IO_PIN_ALL);
     io_driver->Config(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_0,IO_MODE_OUTPUT);
     io_driver->Config(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_2,IO_MODE_OUTPUT);
     io_driver->WritePin(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_0,1);
     io_driver->WritePin(IO_I2C_ADDRESS,IO_PIN_2,0);

  }
return ret;
}
```